# Microsoft Access export via ODBC - ODBC Error 1265

Tags: ms-access, odbc, mariadb

I am trying to export a datatable from Microsoft Access 2016 via ODBC Export to a MariaDB. I have tried:

1. do a right click on the datatable and choose "Export" --> "ODBC-Database"
2. then choose the preconfigured ODBC User-DSN

Then I get the ODBC-Call Error:

"ODBC-Driver[...] Data truncated for column 'TotRev' at row 1 [#1265]"

[image: Error Message Picture]

I have tried different codings, as I got other error codes before which were related to that.

I would really appreciate a hint for this solution. The used Database is MariaDB with utf8-mb4 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem: One specific characteristic with Access is that there exists a datatype currency. This is the problem and so the question is how to get rid of it. Just changing the datatype did not work, as Access run out of memory. The reason is, that Access tries to keep both tables (old datatype + new datatype) in memory.

To solve this problem I found a nice explanation on Microsoft pages. What I did is to follow the hint on this page:

[Microsoft forum entry by John W. Vinson/MVP](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d3742777-565f-492a-add5-49462166d884/microsoft-access-cant-change-the-datatype-there-isnt-enough-disk-space-or-memory?forum=accessdev)

Here his advice:

"[...]An alternative way to accomplish this task requires a couple of steps but works with any size table:

1. Rename the table to tablename_old
2. Copy and paste it to tablename, using the option design mode only
3. Change the datatype in the new empty table
4. Run an Append query to migrate the data

It may be necessary to drop and reestablish relationships.[...]"

As I am not familiar with Access here the link to office support how to append an query

[Add records to a table by using an append query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-records-to-a-table-by-using-an-append-query-98a5bd66-2190-4243-9638-8ef649cf3596?ocmsassetID=HA010341485&CorrelationId=954eb69f-4efd-4671-8d05-c7493d8e76ca&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

Having no familiarity at all with MariaDB - my only suggestion is to export out of Access to a neutral format; either text file or excel.

Then on the MariaDB side - import the neutral file.

Comment: Thank your for your advice. I already tried this and other solutions, but there were some problems with the dataypes itsself. So I did not want to analyse the data in detail and searched for a generic approach. I solved the problem, see my answer below.